# When I print documents from laser printer, some part is missing but some printed

Tags: printer

I am refilling the current Brother printer HL-5350DN toner cartridge.
I have printed many documents but now I am seeing that it prints some part of paper with good quality but some part is faded.

The faded part runs from top to bottom.

When I see the cartridge, then I can clearly see that some part of roller has less toner while the other has full toner.

Is there any solution to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that the distribution of ink in the cartridge can cause that when it's almost empty. I usually just take it out and shake it.

Bear in mind that there are two issues here:

- printer companies don't want you using refills, and
- if you shake it too vigorously, the powder might go everywhere.

With the first point, you'll probably find an original cartridge may last longer.

Comment: i will try shaking the printer

Comment: No shake *only* the toner cartridge. Shaking the whole printer could be a bad idea.

Comment: thanks buddy , the printer was very heavy , i was finding it difficult to shake